# incrementing an ORDER BY statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a query that looks like this:

```sql
SELECT ElapsedTime, COUNT(SurgeryID) as numberOfOps
FROM Table
WHERE Doctor = 'Dr. ABC'
AND numberOfOps > 5
GROUP BY ElapsedTime
ORDER BY CASE
  WHEN ElapsedTime = 'Preoperative' THEN 1
  WHEN ElapsedTime = '2 Weeks' THEN 2
  WHEN ElapsedTime = '6 Weeks' THEN 3
  WHEN ElapsedTime = '3 Months' THEN 4
  WHEN ElapsedTime = '6 Months' THEN 5
  WHEN ElapsedTime = '1 Year' THEN 6
  WHEN ElapsedTime = '2 Years' THEN 7
  WHEN ElapsedTime = '3 Years' THEN 8
  WHEN ElapsedTime = '4 Years' THEN 9
  WHEN ElapsedTime = '5 Years' THEN 10
  WHEN ElapsedTime = '6 Years' THEN 11
  WHEN ElapsedTime = '7 Years' THEN 12
  WHEN ElapsedTime = '8 Years' THEN 13
  WHEN ElapsedTime = '9 Years' THEN 14
  WHEN ElapsedTime = '10 Years' THEN 15
  ELSE ElapsedTime END ASC
```

If Dr. ABC doesn't have any results w/ 'DaysElapsed' == 'Preoperative', the rest of the ORDER BY gets ignored - as in the following result:

```sql
'5 Years,6 Years,7 Years,8 Years,10 Years,2 Weeks,6 Weeks,3 Months,6 Months,1 Year,2 Years,3 Years,4 Years,Unknown'
```

How do I make this ORDER BY clause more robust?

Is there any way to include an incrementing variable in the statement, e.g.

```sql
SELECT ElapsedTime, COUNT(SurgeryID) as numberOfOps
FROM Table
WHERE Doctor = 'Dr. ABC'
GROUP BY Time
var i = 0;
ORDER BY CASE
  WHEN ElapsedTime = 'Preoperative' THEN ++i
  WHEN ElapsedTime = '2 Weeks' THEN ++i
  WHEN ElapsedTime = '6 Weeks' THEN ++i
  WHEN ElapsedTime = '3 Months' THEN ++i
  .          .          .          .
  .          .          .          .
  .          .          .          .
  .          .          .          .   
  WHEN ElapsedTime = '10 Years' THEN ++1
  ELSE ElapsedTime END ASC
```

I understand that SQL doesn't allow for such things, but that is the type of functionality which I am seeking.

Thanks

Comment: What data type is `DaysElapsed`? The column name indicates it *should* be a number (integer or long, probably), but it looks like you're storing strings. If `DaysElapsed` is any sort of text data type, you're doing it wrong. If it is a number, you should just be able to `ORDER BY DaysElapsed ASC` without a case statement.

Comment: mysql does have user defined variables for doing increment something as `select *, @r:=@r+1 as rn from table_name,(select @r:=0)x` however you may need to extend the question with more details for such functionality.

Comment: @MartinCarney That was unclear - I updated my post to better reflect the problem.  ElapsedTime is a standardized label - 2 weeks, 6 weeks, etc.  That is why it is a string

Comment: @l3an In that case, you could create a reference table with all the standardized labels and their ordering values, then join on the reference table.

Comment: Does your query even work? You cannot use an aggregate column in where clause.

Comment: @SalmanA probably not - this isn't the actual query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a reference table, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE ElapsedTimeRef (
    varchar timeString,
    int orderValue
);

INSERT INTO ElapsedTimeRef (timeString, orderValue) VALUES
    ('Preoperative', 1),
    ('2 Weeks', 2),
    . . . . .
    ('9 Years', 14),
    ('10 Years', 15);
```

Then join on it in your SELECT, like:

```
SELECT ElapsedTime, COUNT(SurgeryID) as numberOfOps
FROM foo, ElapsedTimeRef etr
WHERE foo.Doctor = 'Dr. ABC'
AND foo.numberOfOps > 5
AND foo.ElapsedTime = etr.timeString
GROUP BY foo.ElapsedTime
ORDER BY etr.orderValue ASC
```

(P.S. I'm assuming your table name is not actually "Table" since `TABLE` is a SQL keyword.)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably write a PLSQL function that transforms `DaysElapsed` varchars into numbers, and then use it like this:

```
SELECT Time
  FROM Table
 WHERE Doctor = 'Dr. ABC'
 GROUP BY Time
 ORDER DaysElapsedToOrderBy(DaysElapsed);
```

The function itself could look like below.
**Note** that this is very basic, and probably will cause errors - treat it only as an example implementation for further improvement.

```
CREATE FUNCTION DaysElapsedToOrderBy(psDaysElapsed VARCHAR) RETURN NUMBER IS

    nCount        NUMBER;
    sIntervalType VARCHAR(100);

BEGIN

    -- Split DaysElapsed to number of intervals and intervalType
    nCount := TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(psDaysElapsed, 1, 1));
    sIntervalType := SUBSTR(psDaysElapsed, 3);

    -- calculate order by value
    CASE sIntervalType

        WHEN 'days'   THEN RETURN nCount
        WHEN 'months' THEN RETURN nCount * 10
        WHEN 'years'  THEN RETURN nCount * 100
        ...

    END

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cursor (which will get you the I++ Logic) to populate a CTE/Temp Table/Table Variable then join the that against the table, and depending on the query, you can order by a column you are not selecting. Long form answer when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query

```
SELECT ElapsedTime, SURGERY_COUNT   from (select case ElapsedTime WHEN 'Preoperative' THEN 1 
                        WHEN '2 Weeks'       THEN 2
                        WHEN '2 Years'       THEN 3 
                        WHEN '10 Years' THEN 4
                        ELSE 0 END AS  surgery_order , ElapsedTime, COUNT(SurgeryID) as SURGERY_COUNT from test_table 
where Doctor = 'Dr. ABC' and numberOfOps > 5 GROUP BY surgery_order, ElapsedTime order by surgery_order asc) as DATA_TABLE
```